# Remove third-party installed Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

So I installed python 2.7.11 a few months ago, now the class I'm about to take uses 3. So I installed 3 and it works fine. I also uninstalled 2.7.11 by going to applications and removing it, but going to terminal and typing which python, the directory is `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`, which means this it's still not removed.

What should I do...leave it alone? I only need Python 3, but this is bothering me a bit.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you leave it and setup a symbolic link called `python` in your user's local library (usually called `bin`)  and put that at the front of your `$PATH`.

Comment: Unless you want to break your OS I would be very careful removing installed versions of python unless you are very sure you know what you are removing. If you want to use python3 just use python3 in place of python

Comment: Ok. Python 3 works now, so I guess I'll leave it. I can't believe how easy it was to remove Python 2 on PC :( Don't have to type python3 or anything either.  Also, the command ls doesn't work on PC, right? Just cd?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question in the post's title, but leave Python 2 as the default `python`. If you want to run Python 3, you run `python3` or maybe `python3.4` or `python3.5`, depending on your installation. The system and other third-party software depend on `python` being Python 2. If you change it, you may encounter puzzles down the road.

I'm not sure if having a third-party Python 2 is good (OS X ships with Python 2 already), but it should be fine.

Edit: Sorry, didn't see there was already an answer. It was posted as I was typing.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, it is the default python. I just installed 2.7.12, and now I will leave it alone. When I use python3 in the future, I'll type python3 instead of python2, correct? I can't remove this third-party Python 2 for some reason. Don't wanna just delete the folder...

Comment: Yes, type `python3` in most cases. Some installations (e.g. from MacPorts) only link ones with version numbers (e.g. `python3.4`).

Comment: Thanks :) Just surprised how hassle-free it was on PC to uninstall. Don't have to type python3 or anything either. Also, the command ls doesn't work on PC, right? Just cd?

Comment: "PC" meaning Windows? I don't know, I've never used it. I don't think Windows uses Python for anything, so I think it's OK to install Python 3 as `python`. If you do that on a Unix system, lots of random things will break because Python 3 often cannot run Python 2 code.